# SharePoint API for Programmatically creating Fields, ContentTypes etc

Tags: 2010, content-type, managed-metadata, column

I am looking for a SharePoint API which can be used to programmatically create Artifacts like Fields, Lists, ContentTypes etc. using SP 2010 Object Model.

The objectives are:

1. Provide simple way of creating Fields and bindings with Content
   Type.
2. Simple API which requires (minimal) code to be written in Feature
   receivers for Upgrading.
3. Should cater to create complex fields like Managed Metadata Fields.

I came across http://spgenesis.codeplex.com/ which is a close match, but as far as I can tell, it doesn’t support the Managed Metadata field.

Has anyone used anything similar in projects?

Comment: The SharePoint API as it is is good enough from what I've seen (even Managed Metadata fields are simple to create with code) - what are you missing? If you code your own or use another, that code will have to be maintained and tested with EVERY release of EVERY CU released.

Comment: If you look at the code in spgenesis, at the core the fields are created by the AddFieldAsXML method. So I think it should be easy enough to maintain. The benefit of using a framework is that it can reduce the code you have to write repeatedly. Do you think it will be difficult to maintain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can create Taxonomy fields in SPGenesis.

http://spgenesis.codeplex.com/discussions/389764